# Getting book details from ISBN and Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

Let's say I have a list of ISBN values:

```
9781887902694
9780072227109
9780672323843
9780782121797
9781565924031
9780735713338
9780735713338
...
```

How would I use shell scripting/bash to retrieve the Title, Date Published, Author, and Publisher (from a website like bookfinder4u.com)? I'm newish to bash and so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I believe I could use curl, no?

Comment: Don't use bash; if you actually get something working it will be a monstrosity and likely fragile. Python, Perl, or Ruby would be able to handle with little fuss. Also, be aware that the site you reference might throttle or block many requests as it primarily a book sales site, not an ISBN reference.

Comment: To expand on what @msw said: Shell scripting is great for handling business within the operating system/local network.  If you need files manipulated, strings converted, searching done, sorting done, connections made, etc, then shell scripting is the way to go.  The second you leave the realm of the OS, shell scripting loses a lot of its power.  More directly, bash has no real tools to go out to the web and do things like this, whereas other languages like Python have several libraries.

Comment: After researching some, yes, Python and Perl would be more effective. I could use curl to get the website source and then use a script to input the isbn into the correct area though? Any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: Don't bother with curl when [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) is a part of Python as are various [xml modules](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/xml.html) which will help you extract stuff from HTML.

Comment: can you use php instead? check if you've php installed by running `which php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then echo "Usage: $0 <ISBN number>" ; exit 1 ; fi
curl -sL 'http://www.bookfinder4u.com/IsbnSearch.aspx?isbn='$1'&mode=direct'
```

That will get you the page, but parsing that response with grep and sed looks like it'd be really messy. If you know an API that will return JSON or XML, it'd be easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to run `php`, you can use:

**bookDetails.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//you may want to un-comment the code below to make sure your script doesn't timeout
//set_time_limit(0); 
//ignore_user_abort(true);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

//get all the isbn numbers from a txt file
$isbns = file("isbn.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

//lopp all the isbn's
foreach($isbns as $isbn){

    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.bookfinder4u.com/IsbnSearch.aspx?isbn=$isbn");
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($html);
    $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

    $title =  $xpath->query('//*[@class="t9"]')->item(1)->nodeValue;
    $author =  $xpath->query('//*[@class="t9"]')->item(2)->nodeValue;
    $pubisherFormat =  $xpath->query('//*[@id="format_pub_listprice"]')->item(0)->c14n();
    $matches = preg_split('%</br>%', $pubisherFormat);
    $publisher = strip_tags($matches[0]);
    $format = strip_tags($matches[1]);
    $price =  $xpath->query('//*[@class="t8"]')->item(1)->nodeValue;
    preg_match_all('/List price:\s*?(.*?[\d\.]+)/', $price, $price, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $price = $price[1][0];

    echo $title."\n";
    echo $author."\n";
    echo $publisher."\n";
    echo $format."\n";
    echo $price."\n\n";

}
```

---

assuming that `isbn.txt` contains

```
9781887902694
9780072227109
9780672323843
```

The output will be:

```
Javascript: Concepts & Techniques; Programming Interactive Web Sites
By: Tina Spain McDuffie
Publisher: Franklin Beedle & Assoc - 2003-01
Format: Paperback
EUR 48.32

J2ME: The Complete Reference
By: James Keogh
Publisher: McGraw-Hill - 2003-02-27
Format: Paperback
EUR 57.94

Sams Teach Yourself J2ee in 21 Days with CDROM (Sams Teach Yourself...in 21 Days)
By: Martin Bond Dan Haywood Peter Roxburgh
Publisher: Sams - 2002-04
Format: Paperback
EUR 43.92
```

---

run from the `shell` :

```
php bookDetails.php
```